# Duda sobre archivo *.pro

Tags: qt

Si quiero hacer una aplicación que se pueda compilar tanto en windows como en linux, intento hacer esto en el archivo *.pro:

```
unix
{
    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/python3.6m
    LIBS += -L /usr/local/lib/python3.6 -lpython3.6m
    DEPENDPATH +=  /usr/include/python3.6m
}

win32
{
    INCLUDEPATH += C:\Python\Python37\include
    LIBS += -L C:\Python\Python37\libs -lpython37
    DEPENDPATH += C:\Python\Python37\include
}
```

De forma que supuestamente busco las librerías o cabeceras en una u otra ruta, según en que ordenador esté.

Sin embargo cuando estoy en linux se queja de las rutas de windows y viceversa, por lo que he de comentar las líneas que no proceden en cada caso.

¿Estoy haciendo algo mal o este es el comportamiento esperado?
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De la [documentación de qmake](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html):

> #### Scope Syntax
>
> Scopes consist of a condition followed by an opening brace on the same line, a sequence of commands and definitions, and a closing brace on a new line.
>   The opening brace must be written on the same line as the condition.

Traducción libre por mi parte:

> #### Sintaxis de los ámbitos.
>
> Un ámbito consiste en una condición **seguida en la misma línea** de una llave de abrir, y a continuación una secuencia de comandos y definiciones; para terminar con una llave de cerrar en una nueva línea.
>   **La llave de abrir ha de estar en la misma línea que la condición**.

Poco que añadir.

Comment: Nunca pensé que mi manía obsesiva por no poner las llaves al mismo nivel que la línea me traería este problema :O Gracias!